# Why don't insert-in-front-hooks run?

Tags: hooks, text-properties, text

Open a scratch buffer, paste the following an evaluate it:

```
(insert (propertize "hello" 'insert-in-front-hooks
                    (list (lambda (&rest unused) (message "test")))))
```

Typing characters on either side of the resulting "hello" text won't cause the test message to display. [According to the documentation](http://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Changing-Properties.html) [it should](https://www.gnu.org/software/emacs/manual/html_node/elisp/Special-Properties.html#Special-Properties), so I assume I'm doing something wrong. What gives? I've also tried `'insert-behind-hook` and it doesn't appear to fire either.

Emacs version 24.4.1. Tested with -Q as well.

Comment: Boy-oh-boy -- there sure aren't very many examples by Googling.  You may find a few more examples if you use "overlay-put" "overlay" "insert-in-front-hooks" "emacs":  http://nschum.de/src/emacs/tempo-snippets/tempo-snippets.el and https://github.com/Bruce-Connor/names/blob/master/tests/auctex-11.87.7/prv-emacs.el and http://home.online.no/~jood/emacs/bm-1.21.el  Sorry, I couldn't be of more help.

Comment: Maybe what you're doing wrong is to assume that you're doing something wrong ;-)

Comment: @lawlist: I'm using text properties though not overlays, I actually tried with overlays and with those it worked, but I would prefer to use text properties

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I yank your code into `*scratch*`, switch to `fundamental-mode` (which turns of the minor mode `font-lock-mode`), and only then evaluate the expression; then it works.

Actually it shouldn't make a difference whether `font-lock-mode` is enabled or not for properties that are not a member of `font-lock-extra-managed-props`. So you might be right that there is a bug, as it does appear to matter in this particular case whether that minor-mode is enabled or not.

Comment: I was unable to duplicate this experiment in a fundmamental-mode buffer -- i.e., the word "**test**" does not appear in the `*Messages*` buffer or the echo-area or the `*scratch*` buffer.

Comment: I was actually able to duplicate this. @lawlist did you try with -Q and emacs 24.4.1?

Comment: @tarsius: Why doesn't font lock only touch the properties it cares about, or just add to the existing list? That seems like terrible behavior. Using overlays complicates my implementation because they don't play nice with undo :/

Comment: @Joseph Garvin -- thank you for the suggestion.  I just downloaded a fresh copy from http://emacsformacosx.com/ of `GNU Emacs 24.4.1 (x86_64-apple-darwin10.8.0, NS apple-appkit-1038.36) of 2014-10-20 on builder10-6.porkrind.org` with no user configuration file and still was unable make the word "**test**" appear in any buffer.  Perhaps it's a bug in the OSX versions of Emacs.

Comment: @JosephGarvin Well, it's just opt-out instead of opt-in. With makes sense since you, or some package, can add new entries to `font-lock-keywords` at any time. It's not really feasible to parse those entries for the properties which are being set using font-lock.

Comment: @tarsius: I'm not sure I understand you. insert-in-front-hooks is a list, all font lock mode needs to do is add to it instead of clobbering it.

Comment: I am getting a sense this might be a [XY problem](http://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/66377/what-is-the-xy-problem), so what is it you want to do with it once this works as you would expect it too?

Comment: @tarsius: It's not an XY problem, it's a straight forward question about why emacs doesn't act as documented, and you answered it well ;) I just think it's a bug for font lock mode to clobber the property.

Comment: Hm, seems I was wrong about this being opt-out. According to `font-lock-extra-managed-props` it's supposed to be opt-in, so it looks like this could indeed be a bug. But depending on what you want to actually use this for it might still be that you would be better of using overlays or `font-lock-add-keywords`, that's what I was getting at with the XY remark.

Comment: I'm having this problem too. According to your conversation, it is because font-lock-mode messes with the insert-in-front-hooks? Then what can I do to use this property normally alongside font-lock-mode?